# How to register ContainerRequestFilter and pass a variable into it?

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jersey, jax-rs

Is there any way to register ContainerRequestFilter into ResourceConfig with passing variable into its constructor?

Following is the filter code

```
public class TestRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{
   String operationType;

   public TestRequestFilter (){}

   public TestRequestFilter (String opType){
      this.operationType = opType;
   }
   
   @Override
   public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
   }
}
```

In order to register this filter I used ResourceConfig as follows

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

/**
 * Register JAX-RS application components.
 */
public MyApplication () {
    register(TestRequestFilter.class);
    register(JacksonFeature.class);
    register(CustomerResource.class);
    register(Initializer.class);
    register(JerseyResource.class);
}
}
```

Is there any way where I could register this filter with opType constructor?

Comment: Did you try using the overload [ResourceConfig.register(Object)](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html#register-java.lang.Object-), such as `register(new TestRequestFilter("op-type"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create class with a single constructor, create object and register created object.

```
public class TestRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{
   private String operationType;

   public TestRequestFilter (String opType){
      this.operationType = opType;
   }
   
   @Override
   public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
       //your code
   }
}
```

registration:

```
ResourceConfig.register(new TestRequestFilter("osType"));
```